# Filter DDL based on selection of other DDL

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a dropdownlist that looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="FirstDDL" name="FirstDDL">
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
    <option value="3">Option3</option>
</select>
```

And another dropdownlist that looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="SecondDDL" name="SecondDDL">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
    <optgroup label="Option1">
        <option value="12">SubOption1Value1</option>
        <option value="13">SubOption1Value2</option>
        <option value="14">SubOption1Value3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Option2">
        <option value="49">SubOption2Value1</option>
        <option value="50">SubOption2Value2</option>
        <option value="51">SubOption2Value3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Option3">
        <option value="33">SubOption3Value1</option>
        <option value="34">SubOption3Value2</option>
        <option value="35">SubOption3Value3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Now, based on the selection of the first dropdownlist, I want the second dropdownlist to be filtered.

So if I select `Option1` in the first dropdownlist.. then the second dropdownlist should show only the options under `<optgroup label="Option1">`

I have this so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#FirstDDL").change(function () {
        var selectedOption = $("option:selected", this);
        var selectedText = selectedOption.val();

        switch (selectedText) {
            case 1:
                // here is where I need to set the values of the second dropdownlist
        }

    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/q/9275026/656243

Answer (score 1):

You can populate the second dropdown dynamically. 
Example:
...

```
switch (selectedText) {
            case 1:
                $("<option/>", { value: 12, html: "SubOption1Value1" }).appendTo($("secondDDL"));
                $("<option/>", { value: 13, html: "SubOption1Value2" }).appendTo($("secondDDL"));
                $("<option/>", { value: 14, html: "SubOption1Value3" }).appendTo($("secondDDL"));
}
```

...

Answer (score 1):

You can hide all the option groups, and conditionally show only the option group that's been selected from the first dropdown.

**Using a hard-coded case statement:**

https://jsfiddle.net/mbrj7t2b/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#FirstDDL").change(function () {
        var thisValue = $(this).val();

        var $optGroups = $("#SecondDDL optgroup");
        $optGroups.hide();

        switch (thisValue) {
            case "1":
                $optGroups.filter("[label='Option1']").show();
                break;
            case "2":
                $optGroups.filter("[label='Option2']").show();
                break;
            case "3":
                $optGroups.filter("[label='Option3']").show();
                break;
        }

    });
});
```

---

**Using an attribute for dynamic hiding/showing:**

Personally, I don't like hard-coding things when I don't have to. I'd add an attribute to the option groups so that the hiding/showing can be done dynamically.

https://jsfiddle.net/mbrj7t2b/2/

Notice the added `data-optgroupval`, whose value matches the related option from the first dropdown.

```
<select class="form-control" id="FirstDDL" name="FirstDDL">
    <option>Select Option 1</option>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="SecondDDL" name="SecondDDL">
    <option value="">Select Option 2</option>
    <optgroup label="Option1" data-optgroupval="1">
        <option value="12">SubOption1Value1</option>
        <option value="13">SubOption1Value2</option>
        <option value="14">SubOption1Value3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#FirstDDL").change(function () {
        var thisValue = $(this).val();

        var $optGroups = $("#SecondDDL optgroup");
        $optGroups.hide();

        $optGroups.filter("[data-optgroupval="+thisValue+"]").show();

    });
});
```

Comment: I have the first option you answerd, but my 2nd dropdownlist is not filtering..

Comment: Do your values in the first dropdown match the values in the `case` statements? And note, it's hiding the options based on `label`, so if your labels are not `Option1`, `Option2`, etc, you will need to edit the `filter("[label='Option1']")` portions of the case statements as well.